# Method that takes type of object to create and type of interface it should return - is it possible?

Tags: c#, generics, reflection

Imagine C# code like this

```
ISomeInterface someVar = creator.Create(typeof(SomeClass), 
                                        typeof(ISomeInterface));
```

What should happen? Method creator.Create takes two parameters: first is a type of an object to be created, second is a type that method should cast newly created object to and return as that type.

So, like in example code: we want use interface we know class implements so we ask for creation of object and specify that returned type should be that interface we are interested in.

Is is even possible to implement it somehow? Generics, reflection, dynamic method creation based on some complicated generics declaration? something more sophisticated? I'm open for suggestions.

Of course we are not taking into consideration simplest solution that is explicitly casting returned value to ISomeInterface. Method should return created object as interface we asked for.

If you wonder what do I need it for I'm trying to complicate my working code in futile pursuit of some clever way of simplifying my class factory :)

**EDIT**:

Current generic method Create:

```
public T Create<T>(Type type)
{
   return (T)Activator.CreateInstance(type);
}
```

But this is not what I want which is provide two types and basically create object of first but return as second. It is not a case that I have Create method for different interfaces implemented in my codebase.

Further example of usage:

```
  IFoo f = Create(typeof(Foo), typeof(IFoo));
  IBar b = Create(typeof(Bar), typeof(IBar));
```

So, as you can see method returns different interfaces each time according to type provided in second parameter. And there is no way to use type constrains or I don't see how to do it.

Comment: Note that you don't get two distinct objects when you cast an object to an interface, an interface is just a different way of looking at an object. In other words, since your method is not generic, it will have to return `object` anyway, so you might as well just do the casting outside the method.

Comment: that is what I'm afraid of, but if there is no other way...

Comment: Would you explain a little about what this method is to be used for? I'm at a loss to understand why you want to create an object of type `A` but return it as type `B`. If the receiver of the method's return value is of type `B`, but wants to call a method on type `A`, you'll just have to cast it back to `A` anyway...

Comment: Given your example of usage, here's why I'm confused: What is the difference between `IFoo f = Create(typeof(Foo), typeof(IFoo));` and `IFoo f = new Foo();`? In both cases f will be assigned an instance of Foo which will be treated as IFoo.

Comment: I want to remove direct object creation and move it completely into class factories. and types to create won't be passed directly as in my examples but hidden behind enums or something like that

Comment: Typically you would do that by telling the factory what interface you want an implementation of and letting *it* determine which concrete type to return... wouldn't you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want your `Create()` method to return `ISomeInterface` without having to explicitly cast, then you obviously need to make it `Create<ISomeInterface>()`.

To dynamically construct and instance of passed type you obviously need to use reflection, though `Activator` would make it easier.

Comment: obviously that is how it works now but I was hoping to get rid of explicit passing of interface type. probably will have to leave it like it until better generics in next .Net :)

Comment: I'm accepting this answer but as it is closest to actual possible solution but real answer is that this kind of method is not possible to do with today's C# grammar

Answer (score 2):

Off the top of my head, you could do something like this:

```
public I Create<T, I>() where T : I {
    if(typeof(I).IsInterface) {
        return Activator.CreateInstance<T>();
    }
    /* Handle non-interface I calls with exception, etc */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This does not seem like a very safe thing to do.

```
public TResult CreateToType<TType,TResult>() where TType : new() where TResult : class
{
    return new TType() as TResult;
}
```

Edit - hmm this actually won't do what you want, as your trying to cast to an interface. Woops.

Answer (score 0):

You could use generic [type constraints](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5x73970%28v=vs.80%29.aspx):

```
public T Create<T,U,V> (U var1, V var2) 
where T: ISomeInterface 
where U: SomeClass
where V: ISomeInterface
{ 
 //Some code
}
```

Comment: I know about type constraints but unfortunately that is not what I looking for

Comment: That's gotta be the least-generic generic method I've ever seen. What's the use of constraining U to be a specific concrete type? :S

Comment: in place of U you can send class derived from SomeClass

Comment: So the second argument is there just to declare the type you want to cast to ?

Comment: @Yochai: yes, second argument just specifies returned type that created object is casted to. of course I can use Create<ISomeInterface>(typeof(SomeClass)) but was hoping to drop need for explicit <ISomeInterface> part

Comment: I don't think you can beat the explicit calling.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are referring to Duck Typing, if it looks like a duck then it is a duck!

You should check out a few of these links

[Wikipedia Duck Typing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duck_typing)

[Duck Typing Explained](http://haacked.com/archive/2007/08/19/why-duck-typing-matters-to-c-developers.aspx)

Comment: oh, I never heard of it, interesting concept, maybe duck will save me :) but for now I don't see a way to return asked interface. need to read more carefully